# How to update the meta tag in ionic dynamically? So that it can work in facebook social sharing

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4, meta-tags

In the ionic project, there is only one `head` section where we write all the `meta tag` that is in the `index.html` page. For example, to make the Facebook sharing work perfectly we need this `meta tag` given bleow:

```
<meta property="og:title" content="Title">
<meta property="og:description" content="description">
<meta property="og:image" content="Image Url you want to show">
<meta property="og:url" content="http://yourUrl.com">
```

So how can we update this meta tag from other pages?  For example, if we go to a `news detail` page the `meta tag` of that page will be changed accordingly. So how can I achieve this in my Ionic4 with angular project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my existing `Ionic 4` project, I want to use `Angular Universal` but I got into so many errors. So I created a new project using `Ionic 5`. And move all my previous work to the new `Ionic 5`. I follow these steps to add `Angular Universal` to my project. 
At first, create an app and update it to the latest version of Angular using these commands.

```
ionic start myApp blank --type angular
cd myApp
ng update @angular/core @angular/cli
npm install @angular/animations
```

Then add `Express engine` for `Angular Universal` using this command.

```
ng add @nguniversal/express-engine
```

Then you need to install the `@ionic/angular-server` module using this command.

```
npm install @ionic/angular-server@dev
```

For testing in the localhost, your server-side rendering is working correctly you need to use this command.

```
npm run dev:ssr
```

For more detailed information on how to setup Angular Universal for server-side-rendering you can see the `ionic blog` link [SSR with Angular Universal And Ionic](https://ionicframework.com/blog/ssr-with-angular-universal-and-ionic/).

After setting, angular universal you need to add `title`, `add`, or `update` `meta tag`. You can follow my sample code given below:

```
import { Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import { Title, Meta } from '@angular/platform-browser';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-sample',
  templateUrl: './sample.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['./sample.page.scss'],
})
export class SamplePage implements OnInit {
  constructor(private titleService: Title, private meta: Meta) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.titleService.setTitle("Your Title");
    this.meta.updateTag({ property: 'og:url', content:'http://yoururl.com'});
    this.meta.updateTag({ property: 'og:title', content:"Your Title" });
    this.meta.updateTag({ property: 'og:image', content: "your image link"});
    this.meta.updateTag({ property: 'og:description', content:  "description"});
  }

}
```

Now your social share will work perfectly. Because when it crawls not it will get the metatag with data. You need to update the meta tag based on the social share you want to add.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you can do it in a way similar to this:

```
var link = document.createElement('meta');
  link.setAttribute('property', 'og:url');
  link.content = document.location;
  document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(link);
```

Comment: Your solution might work. But I find a solution that will dynamically change the meta tag. But after changing the meta tag dynamically that meta tag is not used by Facebook while used share with Facebook. Facebook used the meta tag from the `index.html` `head` tag meta only.

Answer (score 0):

I got this working last week using Renderton [as described in this post by](https://fireship.io/lessons/seo-angular-part-2-firebase-cloud-functions-middleware-for-rendertron/)  Jeff Delaney. You'll still need to setup server side rendering (SSR) [through this artcle](https://ionicframework.com/blog/ssr-with-angular-universal-and-ionic/). Lastly, make sure none of your code references the window, which will break SSR and Rendetron.

Answer (score 0):

One can use ionic's pre build hooks to modify the index.html after building. Add hooks in your `ionic.config.json` file

```
{
  "name": "xxxx",
  "integrations": {
    "capacitor": {}
  },
  "type": "vue",
  "id": "xxxxx",
  "hooks": {
     "build:after": "./deploy/after-build.js"
   }
}
```

and then in your project folder (top level) create folder `deploy` with file `after-build.js` with following content:

```
var fs = require('fs')
module.exports = (ctx) => {
   const index = `${ctx.project.dir}/dist/index.html`;
   fs.readFile(index , 'utf8', (err, html) => {
      const meta = '<meta name="NEW-META" />';
      html = html.replace(/<meta name="OLD-META".*?">/, meta);
      fs.writeFile(index, html, 'utf8', err => err && console.log( err ));
   });
};
```